# TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'fieldnames'

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I have done a web scrape on a website for practice and I am trying to put the data into a pandas dataframe that can be exported to a csv and when I come to a point a `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'fieldnames'` shows up. I want to write the file using the csv module. Can someone explain how the error has come to happen and how to solve it? My code is as follows:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv

my_url = 'https://www.allagents.co.uk/find-agent/london/'

uClient = uReq(my_url)

page_html = uClient.read()

uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

containers = page_soup.findAll('div', {'class':'itemlabel3'})

filename = "webscrape.csv" 
records = []

for container in containers:
    comp_name   = container.find('div', {'class':'labelleft2 col-md-10'}).div.h4.a.text

    address=container.find('div', {'class':'labelleft2 col-md-10'}).div.p.text.replace('\n','')

    tel         = container.find('div', {'class':'labelleft2 col-md-10'}).div.find('p', {'style':'clear: both; margin-bottom: 15px;'}).strong.text

    records.append({'company': comp_name, 'address': address, 'telephone': tel})
writer = csv.DictWriter(filename, "w", fieldnames=['company', 'address', 'telephone'])

writer.writeheader()

for r in records:
    writer.writerow(r)
```

Error comes on line :

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(filename, "w", fieldnames=['company', 'address', 'telephone'])
```

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which line of code causes the error?

Comment: and which version of Python?

Comment: @jwm: Only Python 3 has `urllib.request` as a module.

Comment: @HD: please [edit] your question to add details that are missing.

Comment: Version : Python 3.6.5

Comment: DictWriter doesn't take a filename and mode. Use `open()` to open a file for writing, then pass the result of that call to `DictWriter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `csv.DictWriter`, the first two arguments are a file object (not a file name) and then `fieldnames` (which you specified as `"w"`). Try this:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, ['company', 'address', 'telephone'])
    # write stuff in this block
```

Comment: The `"w"` is the file mode, and should be passed to the `open()` call.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your call to `DictWriter` has too many parameters:

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(filename, "w", fieldnames ...
                                   ^
                           what is this?
```

I assume it should be:

```
f = open(filename, 'w')
writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames ...
```

In your call the `fieldnames` parameter is assigned `"w"`, but you are also supplying your own version as a list.

Comment: It only takes an open file object, not a filename.

Comment: That's not the cause of the reported error, but I'll add that as the next step.